# Retrofit CLEARTEXT communication not enabled for client

Tags: android, retrofit

i am working with Retrofit library on my project, but it seems that Retrofit block non https requests. 
I tried by adding in the `application` tag in Manifest.xml

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

but didn't work, i also tried another solution by adding under `res/xml` a security confing file:

```
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://my subdomain/</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

and link it in `application` tag in the Manifest.xml :

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

both of the solution didn't work. 
how can i avoid this error ?

NB: my code works fine when i test with `https` request, and for testing purposes we are working in a subdomain which use `http`.

Comment: Struggling with same issue in Android using Refit and Xamarin.Forms - perhaps there is just a config on the Refit side I have to dig up...

Comment: did you tried with xml config file ?

Comment: can you try `<domain includeSubdomains="true"><my subdomain></domain>`, ie, without the protocol?

Comment: check out my comment on @Sagar Chapagain answer

Answer (score 14):

Just was having this exact problem, not sure if the solution for you will be the same. But in my case I was using `okhttp3` as my http client, and when building my client I had to specify the connection specs like so:

```
val specs = listOf(ConnectionSpec.CLEARTEXT, ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)

client.connectionSpecs(specs)
```

Previously I was only setting `MODERN_TLS`, so in order to allow my library to accept http connections I had to add the `CLEARTEXT` spec

Comment: check out my comment on @Sagar Chapagain answer

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks @Quinn

Answer (score 1):

You can include urls without specifying `http://` for urls. Example of website `http://mywebsite.com` and ip address `http://192.168.1.1`, you can write like below:

```xml
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">mywebsite.com</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.1.1</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: If you look at the question, he said he already tried this, add had I but it wasn't the solution to the problem.

Comment: @Quinn I had pointed out the mistake he had made and wrote the correct way.

Comment: @SagarChapagain we were forced to deliver the functionnality asap, so we have switched to the main domain, i didn't tested what you mentionned, if that works for someone else, i'll mark it as the correct answer. thank you