# CLEARTEXT communication - Android

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, cleartext

Facing this Cleartext problem with my android project. 
I have almost used all stackoverflow answers, various blogs etc, but android is not allowing me to connect to server. 
This is a very small app, will be used by 20+ ppl to upload some data on daily basis on local network. So HTTPS is a no go area for me.

Manifest version-1

```
    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Manifest Version 2

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" <!-- With and Without -->
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Network_Security_Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.0.2.2</domain> <!-- Debug port -->
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.0.104</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

I also tried creating a minSdk 21 and target sdk 24 project and it was having same problem using HTTPUrlConnection
Please Guide . Thanks.

Some Links i've checked
[Retrofit CLEARTEXT communication not enabled for client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54929747/retrofit-cleartext-communication-not-enabled-for-client) 
[How to allow all Network connection types HTTP and HTTPS in Android (9) Pie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie)

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-all

[Internet permission not working in oreo and pie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55074899/internet-permission-not-working-in-oreo-and-pie)

Comment: have you added the manifest line inside application tag?

Comment: Yes, it is between application. Check updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried to add this to your manifest application,

```
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

instead of

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

Comment: Yes. I have used this in combination with android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" and without it too.

Comment: No, I mean, without of android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config", I am asking that because I had used it before it was working in my case. I didn't use it with the "android:networkSecurityConfig" . So, maybe combine them is not a good idea.

Comment: Yes. Used all combos n separate too.